# Parsing AWS ATHENA outputs

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-athena

Relatively new to Python here, coming from a node.js background, having quite a few issues parsing the output I get `from get_query_results()`

[Documentation Link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_execution)

I have been at this for some hours, i have tried iterating through the `['ResultSetMetadata']['ColumnInfo']` to grab the column names, but i don't know how to tie the `['ResultSet']['Data']` to these items so the code knows which name to apply to each `dataValue`.

I know i need to select the row headers then add the associated objects to those rows, but the logic on how to do such a thing in python escapes me.

I can see that the first column name always lines up with the first `['Data']['VarCharValue']` so I can get all the values in order, but if I loop through `['ResultSet']['Rows']` how do I isolate the first iteration as the column names to then populate with each other row?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Here is my json.dumps(ATHENAoutput)

```
{
  "ResultSet": {
    "Rows": [{
      "Data": [{
        "VarCharValue": "postcode"
      }, {
        "VarCharValue": "CountOf"
      }]
    }, {
      "Data": [{
        "VarCharValue": "1231"
      }, {
        "VarCharValue": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "Data": [{
        "VarCharValue": "1166"
      }, {
        "VarCharValue": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "Data": [{
        "VarCharValue": "3651"
      }, {
        "VarCharValue": "3"
      }]
    }, {
      "Data": [{
        "VarCharValue": "2171"
      }, {
        "VarCharValue": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "Data": [{
        "VarCharValue": "4697"
      }, {
        "VarCharValue": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "Data": [{
        "VarCharValue": "4450"
      }, {
        "VarCharValue": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "Data": [{
        "VarCharValue": "4469"
      }, {
        "VarCharValue": "1"
      }]
    }],
      "ResultSetMetadata": {
        "ColumnInfo": [{
          "Scale": 0,
          "Name": "postcode",
          "Nullable": "UNKNOWN",
          "TableName": "",
          "Precision": 2147483647,
          "Label": "postcode",
          "CaseSensitive": true,
          "SchemaName": "",
          "Type": "varchar",
          "CatalogName": "hive"
        }, {
          "Scale": 0,
          "Name": "CountOf",
          "Nullable": "UNKNOWN",
          "TableName": "",
          "Precision": 19,
          "Label": "CountOf",
          "CaseSensitive": false,
          "SchemaName": "",
          "Type": "bigint",
          "CatalogName": "hive"
        }]
      }
  },
    "ResponseMetadata": {
      "RetryAttempts": 0,
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
          "RequestId": "18190e7c-901c-40b4-b6ef-10a5013b1a70",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
              "date": "Mon, 01 Oct 2018 04:51:14 GMT",
                "x-amzn-requestid": "18190e7c-901c-40b4-b6ef-10a5013b1a70",
                  "content-length": "1464",
                    "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
                      "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
    }
}
```

My desired Result is a JSON Array like the following:

```
[{
  "postcode": "2171",
  "CountOf": "2"
}, {
  "postcode": "4697",
  "CountOf": "2"
}, {
  "postcode": "1166",
  "CountOf": "2"
},
 ...
]
```

Comment: Your original question used a Python dictionary as the result (which also seems to be the return value from the docs you linked to) but now it's JSON?

Comment: Sorry I thought the Unicode chars would make it harder to read so I ran json.dumps(AthenaResult)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> def get_var_char_values(d):
...     return [obj['VarCharValue'] for obj in d['Data']]
... 
... 
... header, *rows = input_data['ResultSet']['Rows']
... header = get_var_char_values(header)
... result = [dict(zip(header, get_var_char_values(row))) for row in rows]
>>> import json; print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
[
  {
    "postcode": "4450",
    "CountOf": "2"
  },
  {
    "postcode": "1231",
    "CountOf": "2"
  },
  {
    "postcode": "4469",
    "CountOf": "1"
  },
  {
    "postcode": "3651",
    "CountOf": "3"
  },
  {
    "postcode": "1166",
    "CountOf": "2"
  },
  {
    "postcode": "4697",
    "CountOf": "2"
  },
  {
    "postcode": "2171",
    "CountOf": "2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Unfortunatley i get:

        header, *rows = input_data['ResultSet']['Rows']
                ^
    "SyntaxError: invalid syntax;"

and removing the * results in:

    "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Comment: turns out my cloud9 environment was running as python2.7..

works fine in python3.6 in the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I ran into the same problem today.

Here was my solution:

```
headers = [header["VarCharValue"] for header in results["ResultSet"]["Rows"][0]["Data"]]
parsed_results = [
    {
        headers[i]: results["ResultSet"]["Rows"][j]["Data"][i]["VarCharValue"]
        for i in range(0, len(headers))
    }
    for j in range(1, len(results["ResultSet"]["Rows"]))
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).